# Why do some linux header files define a function to return 0 after the declaration?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am looking at the Linux 4.14 kernel's `include/linux/clk.h` file, and have noticed that some of the functions are declared, and then later defined to return 0 or NULL.

For example:

```
struct clk *clk_get(struct device *dev, const char *id);
...
static inline struct clk *clk_get(struct device *dev, const char *id)
{
        return NULL;
}
```

What is the purpose of doing this? I see multiple C source files that fully define this function and still include `linux/clk.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux kernel comes with lots of configuration parameters. For this particular function, you get the service if **CONFIG_HAVE_CLK** parameter is defined:

**#ifdef CONFIG_HAVE_CLK**

```c
/**
 * clk_get - lookup and obtain a reference to a clock producer.
 * @dev: device for clock "consumer"
 * @id: clock consumer ID
 *
 * Returns a struct clk corresponding to the clock producer, or
 * valid IS_ERR() condition containing errno.  The implementation
 * uses @dev and @id to determine the clock consumer, and thereby
 * the clock producer.  (IOW, @id may be identical strings, but
 * clk_get may return different clock producers depending on @dev.)
 *
 * Drivers must assume that the clock source is not enabled.
 *
 * clk_get should not be called from within interrupt context.
 */
struct clk *clk_get(struct device *dev, const char *id);
[...]
```

**#else** **/*** **!CONFIG_HAVE_CLK** ***/**

```c
static inline struct clk *clk_get(struct device *dev, const char *id)
{
    return NULL;
}
[...]
```

This parameter is defined in *arch/Kconfig* as:

```
config HAVE_CLK
    bool
    help
      The <linux/clk.h> calls support software clock gating and
      thus are a key power management tool on many systems.
```